# Rebol 3 - How do you debug using an equivalent of view/new for Saphirion's Rebol

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I'm trying to do some testing while working on GUIs, but I am running into trouble having console access at the same time.

Rebol 3

```
>> view/new [button]
** Script error: view has no refinement called new
>> help view
USAGE:
    VIEW spec /options opts /modal /no-wait /across /as-is /maximized /minimized /on-error error-handler

DESCRIPTION:
    Displays a window view from a layout block, face (layout), or low level graphics object (gob).
    VIEW is a function value.

ARGUMENTS:
    spec -- Layout block, face object, or gob type (block! object! gob!)

REFINEMENTS:
    /options
            opts -- Optional features, in name: value format (block!)
    /modal -- Display a modal window (pop-up)
    /no-wait -- Return immediately - do not wait
    /across -- Use horizontal layout-mode for top layout (rather than vertical)
    /as-is -- Use GOB exactly as passed - do not add a parent gob
    /maximized -- Open window in maximized state
    /minimized -- Open window in minimized state
    /on-error
            error-handler -- specify global error handler (block!)
```

Looking at the help, I tried

```
view/no-wait
```

and this gives console access, but the REB-GUI window locks up.  What is going on with this?  Is there a way to be able to access commands through the console while playing with the GUI?

Comment: I guess one can switch between using the console/gui by typing the command `do-events` and killing the command with ctrl-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to have both console access and the gui concurrently.

But you could use an area face to enter commands and a button to evaluate those commands in your GUI.

Comment: I figured out something like this, but I am unable to do this because I can't access the text of the area.

Comment: How would you output results?

Comment: If you're just returning a value you could do it like this:

`set-face area-face form do get-face area-face`